# Path Manipulation while creating shortcut in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Using below code i am creating a shortcut.When i do run HP fortify tool i am getting path manipulation issues for the highlighted code.I am new to this.Can anyone please tell me how to correct it.I mean what path manipulation is happening.

string fileName = new data().getdata(object_id,                                Cid,    id_pluf).Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"] + "url";

```
            **var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(start + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);**
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();

     private static void DeleteShortcut(string start, string fileName)
        {
            **if (System.IO.File.Exists(start+ fileName))**
            {

                **System.IO.File.Delete(start+ fileName);**
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use :

```
Path.Combine(start, fileName)
```

instead of :

```
start+ fileName
```

Comment: You should explain why path.combine should be used, and what protections it afford if any.